# Azure App Service - docker-compose file issues

Tags: azure, yaml, devops

I have some issues with deployment.

When I run command below to push configuration it pushes corrupted data:

`az webapp config container set --resource-group ${AZURE_RG_NAME} --name ${AZURE_APP_NAME} --multicontainer-config-type compose --multicontainer-config-file deploy/docker-compose.yml`

As I see, sent encoded data (as base64) cannot be decoded properly:

```
{
    "name": "DOCKER_CUSTOM_IMAGE_NAME",
    "value": "COMPOSE|dmvyc2lvbjogjzmncnnlcnzpy2..." //here
}
```

When I try to dump base64 file, encoded by myself, it decodes correctly. I have checked encoding for both files and these are UTF-8.

This is how it looks in azure configuration page.

[image: azure configuration]

Comment: Also running into this issue, but for me the decoding does not seem to work (`echo '...base64-string...' | base64 -d`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have talked with Azure support about this and they have confirmed the bug and a release is on its way. Here is a bug report and link to the fix: https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/issues/14208

Now known ETA for the deploy, but the support engineer guessed around the beginning of August.

In the mean time, we have worked around this bug by pasting the contents of the Docker Compose file under "Container Settings" in the Azure Portal.

Comment: Looks like its fixed now for me. I'm able to deploy code with previous settings.

Comment: @Papkie, really? Would you mind sharing some details about your deploy pipeline? I've tried different agents but the logs always show azure-cli version 2.8.0, with a hint about an upgrade available. And it was with 2.8.0 the problems started.